# What's the most concise way to make a hash table with data in it?

Tags: hash-tables

I'd like to create a hash table with data already in it. I know I can do so as follows:

```
(let ((my-table (make-hash-table)))
  (puthash 'k1 'v1 my-table)
  (puthash 'k2 'v2 my-table)
  (puthash 'k3 'v3 my-table)
  my-table)
```

But there's a lot of boilerplate here. Compare to creating the same table in, for example, Clojure:

```
{'k1 'v1 'k2 'v2 'k3 'v3}
```

Is there a more concise way to create a hash table with data in it?

Comment: The [ht library](https://github.com/Wilfred/ht.el) contains a bunch of convenience functions for hashtables, including a function to construct them like this: `(ht (k1 v1) (k2 v2) (k3 v3))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the printed representation for a hash table. From the [Emacs documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Hash.html):

> You can also create a new hash table using the printed representation
>   for hash tables. The Lisp reader can read this printed representation,
>   provided each element in the specified hash table has a valid read
>   syntax (see Printed Representation). For instance, the following
>   specifies a new hash table containing the keys key1 and key2 (both
>   symbols) associated with val1 (a symbol) and 300 (a number)
>   respectively.
>
> ```
> #s(hash-table size 30 data (key1 val1 key2 300))
> ```

It goes on with a warning for certain data types:

> Note that you cannot specify a hash table whose initial contents
>   include objects that have no read syntax, such as buffers and frames.
>   Such objects may be added to the hash table after it is created.

So we can create the same hash table as the question in this way:

```
#s(hash-table data (k1 v1 k2 v2 k3 v3))
```

Any attributes not provided (that is, `size`, `test`, `rehash-size`, and `rehash-threshold`) are set to their default values.